# IoT Edge Simulate TempSensor issue

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I came across issue with Simulated TempSensor (on Windows). When trying to run it as a module I am getting following error (logs from docker):Using transport Mqtt_Tcp_Only
Unable to find a root certificate file at c:/mnt/edgemodule/edge-device-ca.cert.pem.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.) ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.<>c.b__79_2(Task t)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at SimulatedTemperatureSensor.Program.d__4.MoveNext() in /opt/vsts/work/1/s/edge-modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/src/Program.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt.Util.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt.MqttIotHubAdapter.d__34.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at SimulatedTemperatureSensor.Program.Main() in /opt/vsts/work/1/s/edge-modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/src/Program.cs:line 28

Comment: Can you show more information about what you have done like configuration and commands?

Comment: Hi Rita, I was following exactly this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-simulate-device-windows when I cloned the sample repo, built image by myself and deployed, it was working.

Comment: Use this command to check the settings and show the logs: `docker exec edgeAgent printenv`